# Problem sending packets based on uid-owner of packet to a network interface

Tags: networking, routing, iptables

I need to route packets from an owner(lets say with uid-owner 'mailuser') to ppp1 network interface, and all other packets to ppp0 network interface. (Assuming the two network interfaces namely ppp0 and ppp1 are up)

So, I used the below-mentioned commands to test the proper routing of packets(which were generated by web browser with uid-owner 'mailuser'), to ppp1 network interface.

Following are the commands used (along with a short description) :

**1. Copied all routes from table main to table 100 and table 200.**

```
sudo ip route show table main
  <route1>
  <route2>
  <routeN>
sudo ip route add <route1> table 100
sudo ip route add <route2> table 100
sudo ip route add <routeN> table 100

sudo ip route add <route1> table 200
sudo ip route add <route2> table 200
sudo ip route add <routeN> table 200
```

**2. Changed the default routes for the tables 100 & 200.**

```
sudo iptables route change default via <gateway_ip_of_ppp0> dev ppp0 table 100
sudo iptables route change default via <gateway_ip_of_ppp1> dev ppp1 table 200
```

**3. Removed the routes in main table.**

```
sudo ip route flush table main
```

**4. Marked the packets if the uid is 'mailuser'.**

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner mailuser -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
```

**5. Added rule to look up table 100 (default route through ppp0) for packets which are not marked.**

```
sudo ip rule add not fwmark 0x1 lookup 100
```

**6. Added rule to look up table 200 (default route through ppp1) for packets which are marked with 0x1.**

```
sudo ip rule add fwmark 0x1 lookup 200
```

**7. Flushed the routes in cache**

```
sudo ip route flush cache
```

I expected all the traffic from user `mailuser` to be sent via `ppp1`, which was so, as seen over `tcpdump -I ppp1`.
But, no response packets were received as inferred by the logs, hence, the browser(whose process has pid-owner `mailuser`) was not able to load any web-site.

So, What could be the problem here?  As the browser is unable to load any web page when default route of table 200 is ppp1, whereas when I changed the default route to ppp0, it was working fine.

I have already checked ping command on both interfaces i.e. Ppp0 and ppp1, which works fine for both.

Please help in identifying & solving the problem of Why sending packets via the other 'ppp1' network interface fails?

Comment: If you've found an answer for this, go ahead and submit it as an answer and then accept it so that future people can know the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that packets that leaves ppp1 have the correct source?
Can you post a tcpdump output for ping command and for browser try to connect?
Do you see a difference?
If you have no answer for the packet that leaving ppp1, I may only assume that has the wrong source.

Comment: thanks for your response.
the ping works fine, but browser connection fails, the problem was with the source address on packet, got it resolved